# Creating a bootstrap grid from a loop in React

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, jsx

I am having trouble using bootstrap to create a grid from a looping function. In the code below, cities_index.jsx has an unordered list(ul) and uses a mapping loop for each item in the array, while cities_index_item is a separate file that creates the li for each item. This operation is happening across two files.

The trouble I'm having is I cannot figure out how to create a row for two li's at a time with a loop. Currently, it is giving each li its own row -- ideally, I would like a have one row for every two li's. I could hardcode them to be that way, but I think it'd be more efficient to have the grid be outputted from the looping function somehow.

Could anyone help? Any assistance would be appreciated!

```
//cities_index.jsx

...

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {
          this.props.cities.map((city, id) => (
            <CitiesIndexItem key={id} city={city} />
          ))
        }
      </ul>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default CitiesIndex;


//cities_index_item.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const CitiesIndexItem = ({ city, router }) => (
  <li className="row">
    <Link to={`/cities/${city.id}`}>
      {city.name}
    </Link>
  </li>
);

export default CitiesIndexItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the [Grid](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) components instead of doing a list, unless you have some specific reason for a list.

With Grids, you can set the class of the div you create in your loop to "col-md-6", which will give each div a width of 50% of it's container, thus keeping it to two components per row.

So you'd have a container div, and iterate to create the CitiesIndexItem components, which would be returning another div with the appropriate bootstrap class names.

Something like:

```
//cities_index.jsx

...

render() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      {
        this.props.cities.map((city, id) => (
          <CitiesIndexItem key={id} city={city} />
        ))
      }
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CitiesIndex;


  //cities_index_item.jsx

  import React from 'react';
  import { Link } from 'react-router';

  const CitiesIndexItem = ({ city, router }) => (
    <div className="col-md-6">
      <Link to={`/cities/${city.id}`}>
          {city.name}
      </Link>
    </div>
 );

 export default CitiesIndexItem;
```

Also might be worth checking out [react-bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io) too.